# ToolTip shows type of child element rather than child element content

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, tooltip

I have created a UserControl for a button which has an image stretched across its surface. I'm trying to display a tooltip for the button, which is more elaborate than a conventional text-based hint. The tooltip consists of title text, a larger version of the aforementioned image and description text. The XAML for the UserControl is as follows...

```
<UserControl x:Class="AdvancedTooltipUserControl" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Button Background="#00000000" Foreground="#00000000" BorderBrush="#00000000" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Command="{Binding DisplayPdf}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="1" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                   Source="{Binding es.ImageNo}">
                <Image.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="250">
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" 
                                       Margin="0,0,0,5" Text="{Binding es.Arrangement}"/>
                            <Image Margin="1" Stretch="Uniform" 
                                   Source="{Binding es.ImageNo}"/>
                            <Border Margin="0,8" BorderBrush="Silver" 
                                    BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                       Text="{Binding es.LongDescription}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Image.ToolTip>
            </Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

When I run the application the button appears as expected (with the bound image covering its surface). However, when I hover over the button, a textual tooltip appears containing `System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel` instead of the more elaborate contents of the StackPanel. I've been wrestling with this for ages now and don't seem to be getting anywhere, so thought I'd ask the experts if they know where I'm going wrong!

Comment: You need to set the tooltip property to a tooltip. Wrap your stackpanel in a tooltip.

Comment: I tried that previously (and have now edited my question to include it). Unfortunately, it doesn't make a difference and the same textual tooltip is produced "System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel".

Comment: I copied your code to try and reproduce the issue. just changed the bindings and image sources. it works fine. Is there any way you have a style that modifies the base style of the tooltip? If not, please link a demo project that reproduces the issue

Comment: @w5m Didn't find any error displaying the tool tip

Comment: @TomerAgmon1 Thanks for confirming the XAML works fine for you. I cannot find a style that modifies the base style of the tooltip. I'll see if I can create a simplified demo project that exhibits the issue. One thing I have noticed is that if I replace the StackPanel (i.e. the one within the ToolTip) with a simple hard-coded text string, that text string is displayed as expected.

Comment: Please make it reproduce...it works fine for me, with or without stackpanel

Comment: @TomerAgmon1 your suspicion that the base style of the ToolTip had been modified was in fact correct (I inherited this code and didn't find the style when first searching the solution). I've since found a ToolTip style definition which when commented resolves the problem. Many thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @TomerAgmon1 if you post your suggestion as an answer, I'm happy to mark it as the official answer.

Comment: Your question is really specific to your case...It could have displayed a giraffe for all I know...it's just intuition that solved the problem. I don't think the answer would benefit other people with similar issues.

Comment: I have tried code above, everything works fine. Just check if your bindings are bound to correct properties. See the pic. https://i.imgur.com/KV3lRwV.png